# Mysql Rows Connection

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by, pivot

I've got a problem with this MySQL query:

```
SELECT `product`.`id` AS 'id',
`product`.`added` AS 'added',
`product`.`quant` AS 'quant',
`product_names`.`name` AS 'name',
IF(`product_features`.`feature_alias` = 'color', `product_features`.`feature_value_name`, NULL)
AS 'color', 
IF(`product_features`.`feature_alias` = 'sex', `product_features`.`feature_value_name`, NULL)
AS 'sex',
IF(`product_features`.`feature_alias` = 'size', `product_features`.`feature_value_name`, NULL)
AS 'size'
FROM `product` 
INNER JOIN `product_names` ON `product`.`id` = `product_names`.`product_id` 
INNER JOIN `product_types` ON `product_types`.`type_alias` = `product`.`type_alias` 
INNER JOIN `product_features` ON `product_features`.`product_id` = `product`.`id` 
WHERE `product_names`.`lang` = 'en'
AND `product_types`.`lang` = 'en'
AND `product_features`.`lang` = 'en' 
AND `product_types`.`type_alias` = 'shirts'
```

It gives this result:

```
|id|added              |quant|name                   |color|sex |size

|1 |2014-01-01 19:45:18|100  |Shirt 100% Cotton (USA)|green|NULL|NULL

|1 |2014-01-01 19:45:18|100  |Shirt 100% Cotton (USA)|NULL |NULL|XL

|1 |2014-01-01 19:45:18|100  |Shirt 100% Cotton (USA)|NULL |W   |NULL

|4 |2014-01-01 21:17:07|50   |Shirt 100% Cotton (USA)|blue |NULL|NULL

|4 |2014-01-01 21:17:07|50   |Shirt 100% Cotton (USA)|NULL |NULL|M

|4 |2014-01-01 21:17:07|50   |Shirt 100% Cotton (USA)|NULL |W   |NULL
```

I want to get this result instead:

```
|id|added              |quant|name                   |color|sex |size

|1 |2014-01-01 19:45:18|100  |Shirt 100% Cotton (USA)|green|W   |XL

|4 |2014-01-01 21:17:07|50   |Shirt 100% Cotton (USA)|blue |W   |M
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT p.id AS 'id', p.added AS 'added', p.quant AS 'quant', pn.name AS 'name',
       MAX(IF(pf.feature_alias = 'color', pf.feature_value_name, NULL)) AS 'color', 
       MAX(IF(pf.feature_alias = 'sex', pf.feature_value_name, NULL)) AS 'sex',
       MAX(IF(pf.feature_alias = 'size', pf.feature_value_name, NULL)) AS 'size'
FROM product p
INNER JOIN product_names pn ON p.id = pn.product_id AND pn.lang = 'en'
INNER JOIN product_types pt ON pt.type_alias = p.type_alias AND pt.lang = 'en'
INNER JOIN product_features pf ON pf.product_id = p.id AND pf.lang = 'en' 
WHERE pt.type_alias = 'shirts'
GROUP BY p.id
```

Comment: I don't think he needs to `group by` the rows he mistakenly created himself by the wrong join. He just needs to learn how *not* to multiply the rows by the `join`. This might produce problems with non-aggregate columns too.

Comment: Saharsh Shah, Thank's a lot! You saved me)

Comment: @user2750845 this is not a clean way to solve your problem - instead of making your query more complex and trying to fix wrong join by adding `group by`, you should fix your join and forget the `group by` completely. See the other answer.

Comment: Thank's Tomas, i think your right. (After some edidting of your solution it worked for me). You may call me stupid but Saharsh Shah solution is shorter, and server time to make both requests is equal. As far as this request is generated by a complex script and atributes as "color", "sex" etc, can be changed for example to "watchtype" the first solution is more convinient for me. But thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You have to join the `product_features` table 3 times, for each of `color`, `sex` and `size` feature types (`feature_alias`) as `product_features_color`, `product_features_sex` and `product_features_size`:

```
SELECT `product`.`id` AS 'id',
`product`.`added` AS 'added',
`product`.`quant` AS 'quant',
`product_names`.`name` AS 'name',
`product_features_color`.`feature_value_name` AS 'color', 
`product_features_sex`.`feature_value_name` AS 'sex',
`product_features_size`.`feature_value_name` AS 'size'
FROM `product` 
INNER JOIN `product_names` ON `product`.`id` = `product_names`.`product_id` 
INNER JOIN `product_types` ON `product_types`.`type_alias` = `product`.`type_alias` 
INNER JOIN product_features as `product_features_color` ON `product_features_color`.`product_id` = `product`.`id` and `product_features_color`.`feature_alias` = 'color'
INNER JOIN product_features as `product_features_sex` ON `product_features_sex`.`product_id` = `product`.`id` and `product_features_sex`.`feature_alias` = 'sex'
INNER JOIN product_features as `product_features_size` ON `product_features_size`.`product_id` = `product`.`id` and `product_features_size`.`feature_alias` = 'size'
WHERE `product_names`.`lang` = 'en'
AND `product_types`.`lang` = 'en'
AND `product_features`.`lang` = 'en' 
AND `product_types`.`type_alias` = 'shirts'
```